# How to make a request in between current request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

I have some controller code that fires another request internally and I depend on the result of the later request. Eg:-

```
def new
    username = params[:username]
    password = params[:password]

    client = OAuth2::Client.new(somekey, somesecret, :site => some_site_url)
    access_token = client.password.get_token(username, password, {:id => something})

    @token = access_token.token if access_token
  end
```

The problem here is, while the server being the same, before even the **new** method is complete, **client.password.get_token** fires another request to generate the token, which leads to circular dependency.

What should I do to solve the above scenario? Is usage of **Thread** going to help?

Comment: Why do you need to request the same server? It is't always a best practice to consum the same sever. Instead use that library directly.

Comment: @Mohanraj Would you please elaborate

Comment: Without making api call to the same sever try to use the that specific logic codes which is written in that API.

Comment: @Mohanraj I guess an answer with an example of your explanation would be very good, Thanks

Comment: @Abhi Please post the code of the `get_token` method.

Comment: @Hoa You can find it [here](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2/blob/3d621270f0a36006820003782dfad4e78fc7618f/lib/oauth2/strategy/password.rb)

Comment: @Abhi Could you please let me know to which controller the `new` method belongs to and what is the value of `some_site_url`?

Comment: @Hoa Controller name doesn't matter, it can be anything that acts as an end point eg:- **/services/new** with services as controller.

**some_site_url** is the URL of server(or resource owner) site.

For more details check [Oauth2](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2) gem